# After converting python script to executable with pyinstaller I get: error while loading shared libraries... Permission denied

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a python script which adds a user using the command `os.system('useradd user')`. This code works fine when run like a python script like this `sudo python script.py`. However, once I convert it to executable with pyinstaller with the command `python pyinstaller.py --onefile script.py`, and run the executable like this `sudo ./script`, I get an error `useradd: error while loading shared libraries: libselinux.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied`. Any idea what is the issue and how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `os.system('sudo useradd user')` solved the issue.